# No podspec found for `React-Core` in `../node_modules/react-native/React`

Tags: ios, react-native, cocoapods

I'm using React Native. I get this issue when I try to upload pods. I've successfully installed node_modules, but I'm getting this problem. What is the problem? If we delete the package-lock.json and node_modules folder, I reinstalled npm. But I'm having this problem when I'm doing pod install.

```
platform :ios, '9.0'
require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'

target '...' do

  # use_frameworks!

  pod 'React', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/'
  pod 'React-Core', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/React'
  pod 'React-DevSupport', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/React'
  pod 'React-RCTActionSheet', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/ActionSheetIOS'
  pod 'React-RCTAnimation', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/NativeAnimation'
  pod 'React-RCTBlob', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Blob'
  pod 'React-RCTImage', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Image'
  pod 'React-RCTLinking', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/LinkingIOS'
  pod 'React-RCTNetwork', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Network'
  pod 'React-RCTSettings', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Settings'
  pod 'React-RCTText', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Text'
  pod 'React-RCTVibration', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Vibration'
  pod 'React-RCTWebSocket', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/WebSocket'
  pod 'React-cxxreact', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/cxxreact'
  pod 'React-jsi', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/jsi'
  pod 'React-jsiexecutor', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/jsiexecutor'
  pod 'React-jsinspector', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/jsinspector'
  pod 'yoga', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/yoga'
  pod 'DoubleConversion', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/DoubleConversion.podspec'
  pod 'glog', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/glog.podspec'
  pod 'Folly', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/Folly.podspec'

  # Required by RNFirebase
  pod 'Firebase/Core', '~> 6.8.1'

  # [OPTIONAL PODS] - comment out pods for firebase products you won't be using.
  # pod 'Firebase/AdMob', '~> 6.8.1'
  pod 'Firebase/Auth', '~> 6.8.1'
  pod 'Firebase/Database', '~> 6.8.1'
  pod 'Firebase/Functions', '~> 6.8.1'
  pod 'Firebase/DynamicLinks', '~> 6.8.1'
  pod 'Firebase/Firestore', '~> 6.8.1'
  pod 'Firebase/Messaging', '~> 6.8.1'
  pod 'Firebase/RemoteConfig', '~> 6.8.1'
  pod 'Firebase/Storage', '~> 6.8.1'
  pod 'Firebase/Performance', '~> 6.8.1'
  pod 'Fabric', '~> 1.10.2'
  pod 'Crashlytics', '~> 3.14.0'


  target '..' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

  use_native_modules!

end

target '...-tvOS' do
  # Uncomment the next line if you're using Swift or would like to use dynamic frameworks
  # use_frameworks!

  # Pods for ..-tvOS

  target 'DeliveryApp-tvOSTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

end
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Podspec was moved from

```
../node_modules/react-native/React
```

to

```
../node_modules/react-native
```

So update the line

```
pod 'React-Core', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/React'
```

to

```
pod 'React-Core', :path => '../node_modules/react-native'
```

Please check it here depend on your react-native version
https://react-native-community.github.io/upgrade-helper/?from=0.60.6&to=0.61.4

Comment: Error code: [!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "React/jsinspector":
  In Podfile:
    React/jsinspector (from `../node_modules/react-native/`)

None of your spec sources contain a spec satisfying the dependency: `React/jsinspector (from `../node_modules/react-native/`)`.

You have either:
 * out-of-date source repos which you can update with `pod repo update` or with `pod install --repo-update`.
 * mistyped the name or version.
 * not added the source repo that hosts the Podspec to your Podfile.

Comment: `No podspec found for 'React-DevSupport' in '../node_modules/react-native/'` from line 8 of ios/Podfile `pod 'React-DevSupport', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/'`

Comment: If you get further 'no podspec found' errors, you may want to review the RN Upgrade Helper app to see diffs in the podfile for the versions you're using. This helped me. https://react-native-community.github.io/upgrade-helper/

Comment: @Noah did you solve the DevSupport error? The podfile for that pod seems indeed to be lacking in the node_modules folder

Answer (score 7):

This error occurred as Podspec was moved to

```
../node_modules/react-native
```

In order to solve this issue paste the following code in your Podfile. inside your target

```
 # Pods for RnDiffApp
  pod 'FBLazyVector', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/FBLazyVector"
  pod 'FBReactNativeSpec', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/FBReactNativeSpec"
  pod 'RCTRequired', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/RCTRequired"
  pod 'RCTTypeSafety', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/TypeSafety"
  pod 'React', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/'
  pod 'React-Core', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/'
  pod 'React-CoreModules', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/React/CoreModules'
  pod 'React-Core/DevSupport', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/'
  pod 'React-RCTActionSheet', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/ActionSheetIOS'
  pod 'React-RCTAnimation', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/NativeAnimation'
  pod 'React-RCTBlob', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Blob'
  pod 'React-RCTImage', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Image'
  pod 'React-RCTLinking', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/LinkingIOS'
  pod 'React-RCTNetwork', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Network'
  pod 'React-RCTSettings', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Settings'
  pod 'React-RCTText', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Text'
  pod 'React-RCTVibration', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Vibration'
  pod 'React-Core/RCTWebSocket', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/'

  pod 'React-cxxreact', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/cxxreact'
  pod 'React-jsi', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/jsi'
  pod 'React-jsiexecutor', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/jsiexecutor'
  pod 'React-jsinspector', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/jsinspector'
  pod 'ReactCommon/callinvoker', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon"
  pod 'ReactCommon/turbomodule/core', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon"
  pod 'Yoga', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/yoga'

  pod 'DoubleConversion', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/DoubleConversion.podspec'
  pod 'glog', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/glog.podspec'
  pod 'Folly', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/Folly.podspec'
```

I've taken reference from [RnDiffApp/ios/Podfile](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/react-native-community/rn-diff-purge/release/0.61.4/RnDiffApp/ios/Podfile)

Make sure not to remove your existing added modules in Podfile.

Comment: for react native 0.62 replace pod 'ReactCommon/jscallinvoker', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon" with pod 'ReactCommon/callinvoker', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon"  ref : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60880105/cocoapods-could-not-find-compatible-versions-for-pod-reactcommon-jscallinvoker

Answer (score 4):

You should upgrade React Native using `react-native upgrade`, but check if all pods necessary to your React Native version are in Podfile when upgrading without this tool (sometimes with it too).

One good tool to check Podfile is the [Upgrade-helper](https://react-native-community.github.io/upgrade-helper/). For example, if you upgrade RN from 0.60.6 to 0.61.4, RN pod dependencies will be significantly different in Podfile:

```rb
# React Native pod dependencies
  pod 'FBLazyVector', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/FBLazyVector"
  pod 'FBReactNativeSpec', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/FBReactNativeSpec"
  pod 'RCTRequired', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/RCTRequired"
  pod 'RCTTypeSafety', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/TypeSafety"
  pod 'React', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/'
  pod 'React-Core', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/'
  pod 'React-CoreModules', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/React/CoreModules'
  pod 'React-Core/DevSupport', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/'
  pod 'React-RCTActionSheet', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/ActionSheetIOS'
  pod 'React-RCTAnimation', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/NativeAnimation'
  pod 'React-RCTBlob', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Blob'
  pod 'React-RCTImage', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Image'
  pod 'React-RCTLinking', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/LinkingIOS'
  pod 'React-RCTNetwork', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Network'
  pod 'React-RCTSettings', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Settings'
  pod 'React-RCTText', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Text'
  pod 'React-RCTVibration', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Vibration'
  pod 'React-Core/RCTWebSocket', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/'

  pod 'React-cxxreact', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/cxxreact'
  pod 'React-jsi', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/jsi'
  pod 'React-jsiexecutor', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/jsiexecutor'
  pod 'React-jsinspector', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/jsinspector'
  pod 'ReactCommon/jscallinvoker', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon"
  pod 'ReactCommon/turbomodule/core', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon"
  pod 'Yoga', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/yoga'

  pod 'DoubleConversion', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/DoubleConversion.podspec'
  pod 'glog', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/glog.podspec'
  pod 'Folly', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/Folly.podspec'
```

Answer (score 3):

I was running

```
pod install
```

inside ios Directory when I encounter this error for **different dependency**. I forgot to run

```
npm install
```

After running this command then pod install. I was able to successfully run the project.

Answer (score 1):

Hey guys this updated pod file save my day.

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'
require_relative '../node_modules/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods'
require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'

target 'Native_iOS_App' do
use_frameworks!
config = use_native_modules!
use_react_native!(:path => config["../node_modules/react-native"])

end
```

Answer (score 0):

Eric's answer is probably the root cause of the problem, *using an RN Podfile layout from a previous/different version of RN*. I got the same error when moving from 0.62 to 0.63.

For people going from 0.62 to 0.63, the [upgrade helper](https://react-native-community.github.io/upgrade-helper/) shows that the very verbose RN Podfile boilerplate that Eric cites is now more succinct (see Som's response - although there are a few more changes).

Personally, I created a fresh react-native project with 0.63 and compared it to what I had. If I had known about the [upgrade helper](https://react-native-community.github.io/upgrade-helper/) I would have used that instead.

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue with React-Native 0.62.2. My package location was incorrect.

Change this

```
pod 'RNCAsyncStorage', :path => '../node_modules/@react-native-community/async-storage'
```

To this

```
pod 'RNCAsyncStorage', :path => '../node_modules/@react-native-async-storage/async-storage'
```