# CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "ReactCommon/jscallinvoker":

Tags: react-native, cocoapods

I just updated to RN v0.62 and running app on iOS gives me following error

```
!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "ReactCommon/jscallinvoker":
  In snapshot (Podfile.lock):
    ReactCommon/jscallinvoker (from `../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon`)

  In Podfile:
    ReactCommon/jscallinvoker (from `../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon`)

None of your spec sources contain a spec satisfying the dependency: `ReactCommon/jscallinvoker (from `../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon`)`.
```

I deleted all node_modules and did npm i. I also did pod install in iOS directory but the issue persists. I also did pod repo update.

Answer (score 375, accepted):

For `React native` 0.62 version

So I figure it out

Replace following line in your Podfile

```
pod 'ReactCommon/jscallinvoker', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon"
```

with

```
pod 'ReactCommon/callinvoker', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon"
```

**Edit:**

If you have updated to `React Native` version 0.63

Delete `Podfile.lock` from iOS folder.
Do `npm i`

Open `podfile` from iOS folder

Delete everything and copy below contents

```
require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'
require_relative '../node_modules/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods'

platform :ios, '10.0'

target 'RNTodo' do
  config = use_native_modules!
  use_react_native!(:path => config["reactNativePath"])

  target 'RNTodoTests' do
    inherit! :complete
    # Pods for testing
  end

  # Enables Flipper.
  #
  # Note that if you have use_frameworks! enabled, Flipper will not work and
  # you should disable these next few lines.
  use_flipper!
  post_install do |installer|
    flipper_post_install(installer)
  end
end

target 'RNTodo-tvOS' do
  # Pods for RNTodo-tvOS

  target 'RNTodo-tvOSTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end
end
```

Replace `RNTodo` with your own project name, cd to iOS folder in the terminal and do `pod install` and everything should work

Also `RN` 0.63 has dropped support for iOS 9

Comment: How to solve this problem permanently? Is it a problem from ReactNative team?

Comment: Note: projects ejected from Expo will show the path as `"#{rnPrefix}/ReactCommon"` so, for clarity, the only change is "/jscallinvoker" to "/callinvoker" in the pod name

Comment: Thank you for adding the edit for React Native 0.63!

Comment: This worked fantastic, on react native 0.63, thanks

Comment: `[!] Unable to find a target named `MyRNTests` in project `MyRNApp.xcodeproj`, did find `MyRNApp`.`

Comment: I received the error `[!] Invalid 'Podfile' file: undefined method '[]' for nil:NilClass.` but fixed it by changing the following line, from `use_react_native!(:path => config["reactNativePath"])` to `use_react_native!`

Comment: Very helpful, thank you for posting the entirety of the Podfile!!

Answer (score 71):

I solved this issue (version 0.63) by changing the line in the `Podfile` from

```
pod 'ReactCommon/callinvoker', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon"
```

to

```
pod 'React-callinvoker', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/callinvoker"
```

Comment: This cause - [!] No podspec found for `React-callinvoker` in `../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon`

Comment: sorry @PiotrPiątkiewicz was wrong on the react version, I'm on 0.63

Comment: this solved my update issue when going from 62 to 63 - thanks!

Comment: Thanks! This solved the problem for me after upgrading RN from 0.61.5 to 0.63.4

Comment: Rocket science!

Answer (score 38):

I think `jscallinvoker` version is deprecated try to replacing

```
jscallinvoker
```

to

```
callinvoker
```

Comment: fyi all, this worked for me when updating expo to 38

Answer (score 33):

RN 0.63 has dropped support for iOS 9

So in pod file
replace

- platform :ios, '9.0'*
- platform :ios, '10.0'*

and

- *pod 'ReactCommon/callinvoker', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon"*
- *pod 'React-callinvoker', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/callinvoker"*

go to the ios folder in the terminal run

- pod install
- run react-native run-ios

Comment: Keep single quotes instead of double quotes if your Podfile uses just single ones. Thank you

Answer (score 16):

#### On Upgrade to React Native 0.63.0

This issue happens to my project after upgrading `React Native` to version `0.63.0` so for the solution I just remove the `Podfile.lock` and delete whole the `Podfile` and add the new content from a fresh install React Native project on the latest version and it means its content should be:

```
require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'
require_relative '../node_modules/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods'

platform :ios, '10.0'

target '[YourProjectName]' do
  config = use_native_modules!
  use_react_native!(:path => config["reactNativePath"])

  target '[YourProjectName]Tests' do
    inherit! :complete
    # Pods for testing
  end

  # Enables Flipper.
  #
  # Note that if you have use_frameworks! enabled, Flipper will not work and
  # you should disable these next few lines.
  use_flipper!
  post_install do |installer|
    flipper_post_install(installer)
  end
end

target '[YourProjectName]-tvOS' do
  # Pods for [YourProjectName]-tvOS

  target '[YourProjectName]-tvOSTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end
end
```

**Note**: *it is obvious you should replace your project name with `[YourProjectName]`.*

After it, run `npx pod-install` command on the root of your project and everything will back on track.

Comment: `[!] Unable to find a target named `MyRNTests` in project `MyRNApp.xcodeproj`, did find `MyRNApp`.`

Comment: The error shows you which targets to leave in your file - did find MyRNApp. So remove all the other targets [MyRNTests, YourProjectName-tvOS, YourProjectName-tvOSTests] and any others you don't have in your setup. Basically, remove any other that doesn't appear in the 'did find' of the error message.

Answer (score 11):

In case anyone is still having issues with React Native Version 0.63.0 then this worked for me

Updating the callinvoker pod as follows

```
pod 'React-callinvoker', :path => "#{rnPrefix}/ReactCommon/callinvoker"
```

Comment: For anyone wants to try this and gets an undefined variable declaration for rnPrefix, make sure to declare rnPrefix to whatever the path in node_modules is to react-native. For example - "../node_modules/react-native"

Comment: Thank you, this should be higher up, the other solutions caused other problems for me

Answer (score 9):

In RN 0.63.0 you can remove all RN pods from you `podfile` and just include the following lines inside the target.

```
config = use_native_modules!
use_react_native!(:path => config["reactNativePath"])
```

Also this line needs to be added after the platform line at the beginning of the `podfile`:

```
require_relative '../node_modules/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods'
```

After this, delete the `Pods` directory, `Podfile.lock` and the workspace file. Then just `pod install`.

Comment: Would appreciate more information about the entire podfile layout

Answer (score 8):

React-Native is now configuring pods dynamically, so you don't need to list each one anymore;

use_react_native!(:path => config["reactNativePath"])

This is what you get from a 63.1 base Podfile:

```
require_relative '../node_modules/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods'
require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'

platform :ios, '10.0'

target 'test' do
  config = use_native_modules!

  use_react_native!(:path => config["reactNativePath"])

  target 'testTests' do
    inherit! :complete
  end


  use_flipper!
  post_install do |installer|
    flipper_post_install(installer)
  end
end

target 'test-tvOS' do

  target 'test-tvOSTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
  end
end
```

Comment: Very simple fix and works as advertised. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Making manual adjustments according to https://react-native-community.github.io/upgrade-helper/?from=0.62.2&to=0.63.2 might help.

You will then have to run the command `cd ios && pod install`.

Answer (score 3):

```
platform :ios, '11.0'
```

I solved this issue (version 0.63.4) by changing as below

```
pod 'ReactCommon/callinvoker', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon"

# Maybe someone is

pod 'ReactCommon/jscallinvoker', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon"
```

↓

```
pod 'React-callinvoker', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/callinvoker"
```

Answer (score 2):

In case you already had **callinvoker** but you still have an error. This manipulation helped me :

```
 react-native start --reset-cache
 rm -rf node_modules/
 rm -rf package-lock.json 
 cd ios
 pod deintegrate
 cd ..
 rm -rf ios/Podfile.lock 
 npm install
 npm audit fix
 react-native link
 cd ios
 pod install
 cd ..
 react-native run-ios
```

Answer (score 2):

Faced this issue while upgrading **Expo bare workflow** 0.38 (RN 0.62) to 0.39 (has RN 0.63). Edited answer of @Pritish did work, But it says this **error**

`` [!] Unable to find a target named `RNTodo-tvOS` in project `RNTodo.xcodeproj`, did find `RNTodo`. ``

And

`` [!] Unable to find a target named `RNTodoTests` in project `RNTodo.xcodeproj`, did find `RNTodo`. ``

**Got workaround by changing Podfile like below**

```
require_relative '../node_modules/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods'
require_relative '../node_modules/react-native-unimodules/cocoapods.rb'
require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'

platform :ios, '10.0'

target 'daytodiary' do
  use_unimodules!
  config = use_native_modules!
  use_react_native!(:path => config["reactNativePath"])

  # Enables Flipper.
  #
  # Note that if you have use_frameworks! enabled, Flipper will not work and
  # you should disable these next few lines.
  

  use_flipper!
  post_install do |installer|
    flipper_post_install(installer)
  end
end
```

**What changed?**

ADD unimodules at top

```
require_relative '../node_modules/react-native-unimodules/cocoapods.rb'
```

ADD `use_unimodules!` before `config = use_native_modules!`.

REMOVE

```
target '[YourProjectName]Tests' do
    inherit! :complete
    # Pods for testing
  end
```

REMOVE

```
target 'RNTodo-tvOS' do
  # Pods for RNTodo-tvOS

  target 'RNTodo-tvOSTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end
end
```

For **Android** (If you are getting errors after upgrading)

In `android/build.gradle`
Change

```
ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "28.0.3"
        minSdkVersion = 21
        compileSdkVersion = 28
        targetSdkVersion = 28
    }
```

To

```
ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "29.0.2"
        minSdkVersion = 21
        compileSdkVersion = 29
        targetSdkVersion = 29
    }
```

Comment: Thanks @lakshmeesha, I had to do this as well coming from expo. In my case I also had to add `use_unimodules!(modules_paths: ['../../node_modules'])` so expo could find react-native-unimodules up a folder (I use yarn workspaces and my expo project is a folder below the root).

Answer (score 1):

if you have upgraded react native to 0.65+,
you need to do a change in podfile

platform :ios, '10.0'

to

platform :ios, '11.0'