# App won't load after upgrading to RN 0.62

Tags: react-native

After upgrading to RN 0.62.2 from 0.61.3 using the RN tools for upgrading, updating pod (even had to modify a line in podspec following this to make it work : [CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "ReactCommon/jscallinvoker":](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60880105/cocoapods-could-not-find-compatible-versions-for-pod-reactcommon-jscallinvoker))

My app build but get stuck on the splashscreen. It's working well on RN 0.61.3

This is what i have in the metro console :

```
[Wed Apr 22 2020 18:22:25.108]  WARN     Require cycle: node_modules/react-native-af-video-player/components/index.js -> node_modules/react-native-af-video-player/components/TopBar.js -> node_modules/react-native-af-video-player/components/index.js

Require cycles are allowed, but can result in uninitialized values. Consider refactoring to remove the need for a cycle.
[Wed Apr 22 2020 18:22:25.108]  LOG      Unable to symbolicate stack trace: Unable to resolve data for blob: (null)
[Wed Apr 22 2020 18:22:25.109]  LOG      Running "gamefare" with {"rootTag":151,"initialProps":{}}
[Wed Apr 22 2020 18:22:25.122]  LOG      Unable to symbolicate stack trace: Unable to resolve data for blob: (null)
```

Anyone running in the same issue and any idea on how i can debug that ?

I tried deleting node modules and reinstall everything it does not solve the problem.

When i console log from my `index.js` i have nothing.

EDIT : This is the full error i have in Xcode :

```
2020-04-24 16:46:00.478 [error][tid:com.facebook.react.JavaScript] TypeError: Object is not a constructor (evaluating 'new _reactNative.TextInput()')
2020-04-24 16:46:00.481 [fatal][tid:com.facebook.react.ExceptionsManagerQueue] Unhandled JS Exception: TypeError: Object is not a constructor (evaluating 'new _reactNative.TextInput()')
2020-04-24 16:46:00.490 [info][tid:com.facebook.react.JavaScript] Running "gamefare" with {"rootTag":1,"initialProps":{}}
2020-04-24 16:46:00.490 [error][tid:com.facebook.react.JavaScript] Invariant Violation: "gamefare" has not been registered. This can happen if:
* Metro (the local dev server) is run from the wrong folder. Check if Metro is running, stop it and restart it in the current project.
* A module failed to load due to an error and `AppRegistry.registerComponent` wasn't called.
2020-04-24 16:46:00.498 [fatal][tid:com.facebook.react.ExceptionsManagerQueue] Unhandled JS Exception: Invariant Violation: "myAppName" has not been registered. This can happen if:
* Metro (the local dev server) is run from the wrong folder. Check if Metro is running, stop it and restart it in the current project.
* A module failed to load due to an error and `AppRegistry.registerComponent` wasn't called.
2020-04-24 16:46:00.594 [info][tid:com.facebook.react.JavaScript] Unable to symbolicate stack trace: Unable to resolve data for blob: (null)
2020-04-24 16:46:00.604 [info][tid:com.facebook.react.JavaScript] Unable to symbolicate stack trace: Unable to resolve data for blob: (null)
```

Comment: after some search, i listen to my open port with the commande `sudo lsof -iTCP -sTCP:LISTEN -n -P` under macOS, port 8081 is the only used by my node app.

When building from Xcode i have more explicit error that trigger first : `2020-04-23 11:25:03.953 [error][tid:com.facebook.react.JavaScript] TypeError: Object is not a constructor (evaluating 'new _reactNative.TextInput()')` , some i'm guessing one of my module is using a breaking change from the update of RN : https://reactnative.dev/blog/2020/03/26/version-0.62#breaking-changes

Comment: I did all the update manually by using this tool : https://react-native-community.github.io/upgrade-helper/?from=0.61.2&to=0.62.2 

Still the same error, pods has been updated, i don't know what else to do.

Comment: i've searched all the now breaking change made by react team in this post : https://github.com/react-native-community/releases/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#0620,

I found that two package is use where using some of those function and deleted them (`@react-native-community/status-bar`, `react-native-invertible-scroll-view` which has `react-native-scrollable-mixin` which were using one)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Finally after some search, i had to disable page per page all my component to see what was the cause of the problem. It appear that this package i was using : `react-native-confirmation-code-field`needed to be updated ! (the maintainer was aware of the problem with RN 0.62 and updated it, thanks to him !

I also needed to update `reac-native-firebase` if someone run into the same problem and use those modules.

The best way to debug is to do bit by bit by removing everything and added all the piece back together component per component when log in console are not clear

Comment: Thank! I have the same problem migrating from react native 0.61.5 => 0.63.2, upgrading the version of react-native-confirmation-code-field fixed the issue.

Comment: Wow, what a find. `react-native-confirmation-code-field` was it for me as well; saved me a ton of time. Appreciate it!