# CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "ReactCommon/jscallinvoker"

Tags: javascript, xcode, react-native, cocoapods, podspec

I caught the issue:

> CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod “ReactCommon/jscallinvoker”

when I try to `pod install` or `pod install --repo-update`

How can I resolve this?

> My react-native version: 0.63
> Mac OS: 10.15
> Xcode: Version 11.6 (11E708)

[image: error when I try to "pod install"]

Comment: Could you kindly add some more information, along the lines of what you have done so far, to try and resolve the issue? Or what you have found out through your investigations?

Comment: I also ran into this and found the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60880105/cocoapods-could-not-find-compatible-versions-for-pod-reactcommon-jscallinvoker